# How do I use an If statement to confirm that an integer has been put into a text field in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple Fahrenheit to Celcius number conversion function with a button and two text fields as an exercise and I want to make sure my function will stop when someone puts a value in each text field and then tries to execute the function with onclick?

Here is part of the Javascript everything else is ok:

```
function transfer ()
{
   var fahr= document.form.fahrenheit.value;
   var celc= document.form.celcius.value;

if ( isNaN(celc) || isNaN(fahr))
{
   alert('Please provide a valid number');  
   return;
}     
else if (//what do I put here? == true)
}
   alert('conversion will not calculate correctly with values in both fields');
   return;
}
```

I'm really new to programming I hope there is enough info here.

Comment: What `conditions` do you need to check? Do you want the user to allow to enter text only on one text box ?

Comment: You said integer in your title. Did you mean integer or just number?

Comment: @DON I'm trying to set it up so that if someone put numbers in both boxes they would get the alert and no values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you (try to) check whether either field has a valid value. This can be done by checking whether *both* fields are Not a Number (NaN). To check both condifitions use `&&` (boolean and operator):

```
if ( isNaN(celc) && isNaN(fahr))
{
   alert('Please provide at least one valid number');
   return;
}
```

Next, you seem to want to check whether both fields are filled in (so you do not know direction the conversion needs to be).  So check if *one* field is empty, this can be done by checking of both fields are set (you already know that there is at least one valid value due to the previous check):

```
if (celc != '' && fahr != '')
}
   alert('conversion will not calculate correctly with values in both fields');
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
else if (fahr != '' && celc != '')
{
   alert('conversion will not calculate correctly with values in both fields');
   return;
}
```

So when field one is not empty AND field two is not empty both fields are filled.
In this case you will need to compare against an empty string `''`.

Comment: Comparing it to empty string will not solve him the whole problem. As it is Fahrenheit to Celcius conversion he obviously needs to check if both of those values contain numbers only...

Answer (score 0):

try this

call these functions from each text box  instead of if else.

```
function notEmpty(elem, Msg){
    if(elem.value.length == 0){
        alert(Msg);
        elem.focus();
}
function isNumr(elem, Msg){
    if(!isNan(elem.Value))){
        alert(Msg);
            elem.focus();
}
```

Comment: Easier to use [isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to check if the field contains a valid number...